# Cannot print bash variables in Jupyter notebook cell

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to combine Python and bash commands in one Jupyter notebook shell but only python variables are working but not the bash commands using those python variables. Here is an example

```
username="test_username"
password = getpass.getpass(prompt='Enter your password: ')
!echo "$username"
!echo "$password"
!AUTH_HEADER=$(curl -su "$username":"$password" "https://de.cyverse.org/terrain/token" | jq -r .access_token)
!export AUTH_HEADER
!echo "$AUTH_HEADER"
```

When I tried to execute this in Jupyter notebook cell, this is what I see with an empty blank line for AUTH_HEADER variable.

```
Enter your password:  ·············
test_username
test123
```

I also able to echo username and password but not the `AUTH_HEADER`. I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose each run off shell command `!cmd` starts a new bash instance. Thus the variable `AUTH_HEADER` is not shared between bash instances. Try run cell with bash and run your script there like below

```
%bash
AUTH_HEADER=$(curl -su "$username":"$password"  "https://de.cyverse.org/terrain/token" | jq -r .access_token)
export AUTH_HEADER
echo "$AUTH_HEADER"
```